# Not able to connect to mongo db using aws I AM Role from lamda geting error "Optional module `aws4` not found"

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless

I am trying to  connect to mongo db atlas from lamda and i am using serverless framework.the lamdas are deployed correctly but during the invocation i am getting  an error

```
Optional module `aws4` not found. Please install it 
to enable AWS authentication at Object.
<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/src/deps.ts:178:3)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14) at Module.require 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397) at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397) at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397) at require 
(internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
 { [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set { 'HandshakeError' } }
```

Please note: I am not using username and password to access mongo i am using AWS I am role for  connection to mongodbatlas

Answer (score 1):

Do as the error message says.

`aws4` is an optional dependency of the native driver. Being optional, it is not included in their package.json, and you are expected to install it on the application level.

run `npm i --save aws4`, or add it to the package.json manually and re-deploy lambda.

Comment: "aws4": "^1.11.0",  this is already there in package.json still the error occurs

Comment: @NikhilBiju do you confirm aws4 is in node_modules  in your lambda function? please check it manually on the AWS console.

Comment: try import "aws4" in your function